# Why is % used to calculate hashCode index conversion?

Tags: javascript, hashtable

Let's say my bucket count is 100 for my Hash Table. My hash code comes out to `500` for Key A, and `600` for Key B. These both resolve to `0` for `hashCode % this.bucketCount`, which is a collision for different hash codes.

I'm wondering why `%` is used to calculate the index. Can someone explain the math on this? Why is the index output by that math the place where I should insert my node?

```
HashTable.prototype.hashFunction = function(key){
    var hash = 0;
    for (var i=0;i< key.length; i++){
        console.log(key.charCodeAt(i))
        hash += key.charCodeAt(i)
    }
    return hash;
};

HashTable.prototype.convertHashToIndex = function(hashCode) {
    return hashCode % this.bucketCount;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there are `bucketCount` buckets, the modulus (or remainder) of division by the number of buckets is used to ensure that the result *fits* in the buckets available. If you didn't take the modulus, you'd get results without being able to store them.

Comment: Duh, makes sense. Then if the hashCodes get the same index, I simply handle this collision by walking the returned bucket (linked list) at that index and appending the node to the end of the list

Comment: @Growler Or inserting at the head of the list (or somewhere within the list if you like). But yes, that's typically how collisions are handled.